# What is the error in this code? Interview

Tags: c#, .net

In a recent interview I had this question.

Whats the error here?  I know enough c# but I cant see an error. Can you?

```
Class x {
     protected string t1;
     public int t2;
}
Class y : x {
}
```

Comment: capital letter C in the keyword class :)

Comment: Copy/pasting it into Visual Studio would have answered it also, wouldn't it?

Comment: the capital C, was a mispelling. so thats not the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well in terms of *errors*, we could start with `Class` instead of `class`. In terms of *bad practice*, virtually every line of it is a bad idea in my view:

- Non-descriptive class names (x, y)
- Class names which don't follow .NET naming conventions
- Non-private fields
- Non-descriptive field names

Basically, the types `string` and `int` are okay here - but every other non-whitespace, non-symbolic token would need changing before I let this into a codebase...

Comment: I was looking to errors, but this does compiles.  However from my point of view the real error here is that the fields are non private.  The other are just fxcop issues not real errors.

Comment: @Locaaaa: at my job, FxCop errors _are_ real errors, most of the time.

Comment: @Locaaaaa: It won't compile with `Class` instead of `class`. A non-private field isn't a "real" error in that it's not an error from the compiler's point of view. I think it's more likely I'd end up *occasionally* using non-private fields in very specialized cases than that I'd *ever* have a class called `x`.

Comment: indeed they are, but in an interview I dont think they are looking at those kinds of erros, maybe they are looking at design errors.  If you were the interviewer what would satisfy you as an answer? to me it would be: Non-private fields